# Make <li> list images clickable and maintain formatting

Tags: css, html

I am making a tree control using `<ul>`. Clicking on an item expands or collapses the node.

List images (bullets) are not clickable, so the solution seems to be to hide them and just show my own image. The problem with this is that when an item wraps to the next line, the default wrapping indent behavior of a list item is lost.

How can I achieve what I want in CSS?

Comment: Play around with [`list-style-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-position).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to replace your bullets with images. When you bind the `onclick` event of an `li` to some function, clicking the bullet seems to fire it as well. To bind the `onclick` of the bullet to a different function, wrap `li` text content in a `span` and assign a different `onclick` event; something like:

```
$("li").click(function() {
   alert("I'm a bullet! Glee's awesome!");
});
$("li span").click(function(event) {
   alert("I'm some text! Glee's awesome!");
   event.stopPropagation(); //make sure the li onclick isn't fired
});
```

And a little working demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/7EbVw/6/).

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
li { 
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
```

Can also be

```
#myDiv { 
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
```

This will indent after the first line of your list/div.

You may also need to add a `display: block;` to the element if it doesn't work out.  Haven't tested it but give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Bullets in front of an `<li>` tag seem perfectly clickable to me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5xzNR/ so I think you can just allow your regular `<li>` tags to be clickable.